# How to keep from inserting duplicated rows into a table?

Tags: duplicates, insert, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table MY_TABLE that contains records as follows:

| NAME | ID1 | ID2 | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JESSICA | 12 | 34 | TRUE |
| NULL | 12 | 34 | TRUE |

I want to insert into another table TEST the values from the last 3 columns from MY_TABLE but I don't want to duplicate the rows

I am trying to do:

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN ID1 IS NOT NULL AND FLAG THEN 
INTO TEST VALUES (
ID1,
ID2,
FLAG
)
SELECT * 
FROM MY_TABLE
LEFT JOIN TEMP ON ID1;
```

This is resulting in my table looking like:

| ID1 | ID2 | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | TRUE |
| 12 | 34 | TRUE |

instead of:

| ID1 | ID2 | FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | TRUE |

The issue I am running into is that these duplicated values for these last 3 columns are resulting from my join and I can't select only the last 3 columns in my query because I need the first column for another table I am inserting into as well (not shown and also is the reason why I need to use INSERT ALL here). Is there a way to solve this duplicate rows issue within the INSERT itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can project a column with a row number for each group of rows and use the row number to decide which row to use in your multi-table insert.

```
create or replace temp table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as "NAME",
COLUMN2::string as "ID1",
COLUMN3::string as "ID2",
COLUMN4::string as "FLAG"
from (values
('JESSICA','12','34','TRUE'),
('NULL','12','34','TRUE')
);
      
select   NAME
        ,ID1
        ,ID2
        ,FLAG
        ,row_number() over (partition by ID1, ID2, FLAG order by NAME nulls last) ROWNUMBER
from t1
;
```

That select will produce a result set like this:

| NAME | ID1 | ID2 | FLAG | ROWNUMBER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JESSICA | 12 | 34 | TRUE | 1 |
| NULL | 12 | 34 | TRUE | 2 |

In your multi-table insert, you can then key off the ROWNUMBER column:

```
INSERT ALL
WHEN ID1 IS NOT NULL AND FLAG AND ROWNUMBER = 1 THEN 
[etc., etc.]
```

Comment: A  `DISTINCT` would work, too

Comment: That would reduce rows that are needed for the other tables in the multi-table insert.